# Is it possible to get all the parent of a particular role in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchial (parent-child) role based structure to be used for authorization. I have a simple schema, which stores roles along with the id of their parent. Now I am given a role_id, from which I want to get all the parents of that role.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
  ROLE_ID    ROLENAME    IS_PARENT    PARENT_ROLE_ID
1       1    ABC CORP         Y         NULL
2       2    ABC EC           Y         1
3       3    ABC WC           Y         1
4       4    ABC NY           Y         2
5       5    ABC OH           Y         2
6       6    NY ORTH          N         4
7       7    NY CARD          N         4
8       8    OH ORTH          N         5
9       9    OH CARD          N         5
```

Now, when I am provided with a `ROLE_ID` of `8`, the query should return me:

```
ROLE_ID
      1
      2
      5
      8
```

Since `OH ORTH` is a child of `ABC OH`. `ABC OH` is a child of `ABC EC`. `ABC EC` is a child of `ABC CORP`, I should get `1`,`5`,`2` and `1`.

In the above example, there are only 4 levels. But, in actual situation, there might be many levels.

I tried googling solution to this problem and stumbled up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm). But this is particular to Oracle, and it gives me syntax error when executing queries on Microsoft SQL Server.

Is this possible? I am using Microsoft SQL server on Microsoft Windows Azure.

I have limited knowledge of SQL. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use recursive CTE for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

```
;WITH RCTE AS 
(
  SELECT ROLE_ID, PARENT_ROLE_ID FROM Table1
  WHERE ROLE_ID = 8

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.ROLE_ID, t.PARENT_ROLE_ID FROM RCTE r
  INNER JOIN Table1 t on r.PARENT_ROLE_ID = t.ROLE_ID
)
SELECT * FROM RCTE
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b515e/1)**